# Assignment to a superclass

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

How does one go about assigning to an object's superclass?

Example:

```
classdef foo < bar
...
  methods
    function this = barSet(this,b)
      % Here I want to arrange that bar(this) == b
    end
  end
end
```

How (or can) I implement `barSet`?

Answer (score 0):

When messing around with the base class, you should use the `@`-syntax (read about it [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modifying-superclass-methods-and-properties.html)). For example:

```
classdef foo < bar
...
  methods
    function this = barSet(this,b)
        %# call method in bar
        barSet@bar(this, b);
        ...
    end
  end
end
```

The method `barSet` is a method in both `foo` and `bar`.

This is Matlab's way of extending overloaded methods: if you omit the `barSet(this,b)` definition in `foo`, calling

```
F = foo;
F.barSet(5);
```

will call the method `barSet` in class `bar` with the argument `5`. If you define it, the method can do something else entirely, or *first* do what the version in `bar` does, followed by more specialized stuff (written above as the `'...'`).

Now does this help at all? Because it's not entirely clear to me what you want. I don't understand what you mean by `bar(this) == b` -- is `b` an instance of `foo` or `bar`? And what do you mean with `bar(this)`? A copy constructor? So do I understand you correctly that you mean that you want to overwrite the `this` instance with the `b` instance to it?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this. 
Your suggestion requires that I modify the superclass bar to add a method barSet. I'd prefer to avoid messing with the superclass in this way. 
What I meant by bar(this) (in bar(this) == b) was the cast of this to class bar. Similarly, it was intended that b be of class bar.